# Can I get villagers from other peoples islands to move to mine even if my town is already full?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I don’t really know how it would work but I see people trading islanders all the time in Animal Crossing New Horizons, even if my island is already full is there a way to get villagers from other people?

Comment: My friend was unable to invite my villager to move in until she built a free plot. However, since she was under the 10 villager cap, I don't know if that affects things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an empty plot to invite someone 'in boxes' (that is in the process of leaving another island.)

If you keep speaking to someone on your campsite, they will end up proposing to switch with another resident, at random as far as I know.

Comment: The other option is to buy [Amiibos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiibo).  They are trading cards for each villager, sold in packs, each containing a near field communications chip that can be read by your switch.  You use the Nook stop machine in resident services to scan the Amiibo villager into your campsite.  During each visit they will ask you to craft a souvenir for them (and may give you a recipe to do so so).   After you give them their third souvenir they will be willing to move to your island and will let you choose which villager you want them to replace.